# React render when using onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Wanted to know if there is way you can render the component without constructor.

Below is the my onClick code.  My goal is to render when you click the button so that the button disappears.
I wasn't sure if there was way to render this without creating

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
 }






 <div>
    <h1>Title: {post.title}</h1>
    <h2>Pages: {post.pages}</h2>
    <div>Reviews:</div>
    <button 
        onClick={() => { this.props.addToMyPage(
              {
                  userId: user.user.user_id, 
                  bookId: post.book_id
              }
         )}}>
         Add this to my page
    </button>
 </div>
)
```

d

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { selectBook } from '../actions/index';
import { addToMyPage } from '../actions/index';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { selectUser } from '../actions/index.js';
import { getBooks } from '../actions/index';
import _ from 'lodash';

class BookDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show: true
        };
    }    
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.selectBook(this.props.params.id)
        if(this.props.user) {
            this.props.selectUser(this.props.user.user.user_id);
        }
        else { 
            this.props.selectBook(this.props.params.id);
        }
    }

    renderList() {

        const elems = [];
        const urlId = parseInt(this.props.params.id);
        this.props.list.forEach((list) => {
            console.log("list", list.book_id);
            console.log("params", this.props.params.id)
                if(list.book_id === urlId) {
                    console.log("true");
                    elems.push({
                        book: list.book_id
                    })
                }
        })
        return elems;
    }
    render() {
        const {post} = this.props;
        const {user} = this.props;
        const {list} = this.props;
        const renderList = this.renderList();
        const urlId = parseInt(this.props.params.id);

        if(!post) {
           return <div>Loading...</div>
        }

        if(user && list) {
            if(urlId === _.get(renderList, '[0].book')) {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <h1>Title: {post.title}</h1>
                        <h2>Pages: {post.pages}</h2>
                        <div>Reviews:</div>
                    </div>
                )
            }
            else {
                return (
                   <div>
                        <h1>Title: {post.title}</h1>
                        <h2>Pages: {post.pages}</h2>
                        <div>Reviews:</div>
                        {this.state.show && <button 
                            onClick={() => { this.setState({show:false}, this.props.addToMyPage(
                                {
                                    userId: user.user.user_id, 
                                    bookId: post.book_id
                                }
                                ))}}>
                            Add this to my page
                        </button>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Title: {post.title}</h1>
                    <h2>Pages: {post.pages}</h2>
                    <div>Reviews:</div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        post: state.books.post,
        user: state.user.post,
        list: state.list.all

    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {selectBook, addToMyPage, getBooks, selectUser})(BookDetails);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily show the button based on the state of your function:

```
this.state = {
    show: true
};
```

====

```
<div>
....
{this.state.show && <button 
    onClick={() => { this.props.addToMyPage(
          {
              userId: user.user.user_id, 
              bookId: post.book_id
          }
     ); this.setState({show:false})}}>
     Add this to my page
</button>
}
...
</div>
```

Once the button clicked - you change the state to `show: false` and this will cause the button to be removed from your DOM.

Comment: I have update my code it seems to work but in the console there is error enqueueCallback(...).  Not exactly sure why it is throwing this error.

Comment: When you run it without the setState you don't get the errors? Another option - you can call the `addToMyPage` function outside of the `setState` call, as I'm not sure what exactly this function does (it might interfere with the current object)

Comment: Yeah when I didn't do setState it didn't throw error.
Sorry pretty new to coding, I am not sure what you mean by call addToMyPage function outside of the setState.

Comment: Ah gotcha.  Everything works without throwing errors now.
Thanks for the help.